# Open .asc file inside .tgz.tar archive without decompressing with Python and GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo

I am trying to open an .asc file inside a .tgz.tar archive with Python and osgeo.gdal.

[Here](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#vsitar-tar-tgz-archives) is the link to the official description that this is possible by using /vsitar/

```
#source file name
src_filename = "/evapo_p_downloads/grids_germany_daily_evapo_p_200901.tgz/grids_germany_daily_evapo_p_200901.tar/grids_germany_daily_evapo_p_20090101.asc"

#driver 
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('AAIGrid')

#open file with gdal
src_ds = gdal.Open("/vsitar/" + src_filename)
```

but

```
print(src_ds)
```

gives me a None. I try several other descriptions for path like /vsitar//path or /vsitar/path with and without "" but nothing seems to be work. What am I doing wrong here?

**I Found this solution for opening successfully a tarball**

```
src_filename = "/vsitar/{grids_germany_daily_evapo_p_200901.tgz}/grids_germany_daily_evapo_p_20090101.asc"
src_ds = gdal.Open(src_filename)
print(src_ds)

<osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x000001BEEBEDBEA0> >
```

So it didn't work when I enter the full path like `/path/to.tgz/my.tar/file` instead I have to remove the `.tar` path maybe because gdal knows that in a tarball (.tgz.tar) there is only one .tar file allowed.

Comment: Examples in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gcore/vsifile.py seem to use `gdal.VSIFOpenL`, not `gdal.Open`.

Comment: `fp = gdal.VSIFOpenL("path/to.tgz/my.tar/file.asc" or  "/vsitar/" + src_filename, 'wb+') `
print(fp) gives me also None. maybe it is not possible to open .tgz.tar in one step?

Comment: What version of GDAL? Is it possible to provide a link to the tgz?

Comment: [files can be found on this ftp server](https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/daily/evapo_r/) and the GDAL version is '2.4.1'